# How to cast string array created by calloc, back into string array?

Tags: arrays, c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

In below sample code, under GDB, I want to watch a dynamically created string array as a typical string array:

```
// dynamically create an array of 2 strings, each string has 21 characters.

char **word_list = calloc(2, sizeof(char*));

word_list[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(char) * 21);
word_list[1] = calloc(1, sizeof(char) * 21);

strcpy(word_list[0], "foo");
strcpy(word_list[1], "bar");


// statically create an array of 2 x 21 as a comparison
char word_list2[2][21] = {{'f','o','o'},{'b','a','r'}};
```

In GDB, is there way to cast word_list into a character array so that I can watch its content the same way as watching `word_list2`:

```
(char[2][21]) word_list // this cast shows a bunch of gibberish.
```

word_list1, a 2 x 21 string array created dynamically, showing gibberish when viewed this way
[image: word_list1, a 2 x 21 string array created dynamically, showing gibberish when viewed this way]

word_list2, a typical string array of 2 x 21

[image: word_list2, a typical string array of 2 x 21]

Comment: Given: `word_list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(char) * 21); word_list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(char) * 21);` We don't know the value of `i`. Even if it was `0`, the code is still wrong because it only sets _one_ element and it _leaks_ the first `calloc` value. You want: `word_list[0] = calloc(1, 21); word_list[1] = calloc(1, 21);` _Side note:_ `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1 [by definition].

Comment: Oops, that was my bad, `word_list[i]` was taken out of a loop where i = 0 and 1. It's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

An array of `char *` is not the same as an array of `char[21]`.  So they appear different because they *are* different.

You can change your code to allocate memory for an array of arrays and assign it to a proper array type:

```
char (*word_list)[21] = calloc(2, sizeof(char[21]));
```

Comment: To reduce maintenance, could use `sizeof(char[21])` --> `sizeof *word_list`.

Comment: I changed my code and declared `word_list` as you suggested. Now I can access `(char (*)[2][21]) word_list` as a 2D array. Question is, what does (char(*)[2][21] really mean? I know char* means string, but what is char(*)[2][21]? is it char* string for each[i][k], where i is up to 2, and k is up to 21?